# Using Apache Kafka to maintain data integrity across databases in microservices architecture

Tags: apache-kafka

Has anyone used Apache Kafka to maintain data integrity across microservice architecture which each service has its own database? I have been searching around and there was some posts mentioned about using Kafka but I'm looking for more details such as in how Kafka was used.  Do you have to write code for producer and consumer (say for Customer database as producer and Orders database as consumer so that if a Customer is deleted in the Customer database then the Orders database somehow need to know that so it will delete all Orders for that Customer as well).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to write that processing code

For example, one database would be connected to a CDC reader to emit all changes to a stream (the producer), which could be fed into a KTable or custom consumer to write upserts/deletes into a local cache of another service. I mention it ought to be a cache rather than a database is because when the service restarts, you potentially miss some events, or duplicate others, so the source of the materialized view should ideally be Kafka itself (via a compacted topic)